# Storing state between hook functions

Tags: hooks, variables

I have two functions which I'm hooking into a plugin. Both functions are called (at different times) during a single page creation by the server.

I want to set a flag in function_a which can be read by function_b.

**Question: Is there any problem with just declaring my flag in the global scope? Is there a preferred WP-style for doing this?**

ps. I realize that I will need to be defensive when function_b reads the flag--by making sure that the value was explicitly set, etc.

Comment: How about `add_option`? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option

Comment: @elclanrs -- Thanks for commenting, but `add_option` wouldn't work since options are site-wide, not per session. Also, it stores in the db and there is no need for that when the state only needs to be handled within a single page display thread of execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uing OOP for your plugin it's very easy.

```
class MyPlugin {

    static $flag;

    static function function_a() {
      self::$flag = 'a value';
    }

    static function function_b() {
      if ( ! is_null(self::$flag) ) echo self::$flag; // echo 'A Value';
    }

}

add_action('plugins_loaded', array('MyPlugin', 'function_a') );
add_action('init', array('MyPlugin', 'function_b') );
```

Not using OOP you can use `global` variables.

```
function function_a() {
  global $myflag;
  $myflag = 'a value';
}

function function_b() {
  global $myflag;
  if ( ! is_null($myflag) ) echo $myflag; // echo 'A Value';
}

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'function_a' );
add_action('init', 'function_b' );
```

This works and seems easier, but first solution is better for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the clear examples. You confirmed my supposition.